# Queuing in CruiseControl

Tags: cruisecontrol

I'm using CruiseControl in order to manage my builds. However, I've encountered a small problem when queuing several builds. Queuing one additional build works fine, but when trying to queue more than one additional builds, the builds will fail.

Is there a way to increase the queue size in CruiseControl?

When a developer wants to build something on the buildserver, they send some information via a pythonscript to another pythonscript on the server. This scripts updates the config.xml with the necessary information and force a config update with `http://localhost:8000/invoke?operation=reloadConfigFile&objectname=CruiseControl+Manager%3Aid%3Dunique`. The build is then forced with the `http://localhost:8000/invoke?operation=build&objectname=CruiseControl+Project%3Aname%3D%22"+productName` command.

Is this the proper way to add projects to the build queue?

The buildscripts which are called from CruiseControl need a version id for ClearCase, which have to be updated for every build. Thus the configuration for the projects in the config.xml will also have to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. When a developer wants to build something on the server, the top product is loaded to the buildserver via ClearCase. This top product in turn has its own config-file which states all its subproducts. The problem is quite simple, the first config file is rewritten for every project, making all the projects, except the first and the last, become unloaded. Had more to do with ClearCase, than CruiseControl really :P

Answer (score 1):

Normally you have all projects configured in your config.xml(which you leave mostly untouched).

As you stated in the comments you have to update a certain id for the buildscripts.

Maybe you should update a property file or something similar for each project, that contains this id. This file could be edited by the python script, so that constantly updating the config.xml won't be necessary anymore.

I assume that the updating/rebooting of cruisecontrol leads to the failing behavior.